# Why don't we say Rav Sadiaa Gaon's prayer for before and after baths?

Tags: history, tefilla, showering-bathing, saadya-gaon

In Rav Sadiaa Gaon's prayer book, he lists a short prayer for before and and after baths. Why isn't that said anymore (I'd assume it was said in his time)?
The text I'm referring to can be found here: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&st=&pgnum=148&hilite=

Comment: Why don't we say these either ,from Kitzur סעיף ד 
הנכנס להקיז דם, וכן קדם שיאכל או ישתה או יעשה איזה דבר לרפואה, יתפלל קדם תפלה קצרה, ויאמר, : יהי רצון מלפניך ה' אלהינו ואלהי אבותינו, שיהיה לי עסק זה לרפואה, כי רופא חנם אתה. ואם דבר זה שהוא אוכל או שותה לרפואה צריכין לברך עלי - עין לעיל סימן ג' סעיף ח', יאמר תחלה תפלה זאת, ואחר כך יברך - כן נראה לי, שלא להפסיק בין הברכה לאכילה. לאחר שהקיז דם, מברך ואומר,: ברוך אתה ה' אלקינו מלך העולם, רופא חולים

 

סעיף ה 
המתעטש אומר לו חברו: אסותא. והוא יאמר לו: ברוך תהיה. ואחר כך אומר, לישועתך קויתי ה', דהמתפלל על חברו, הוא נענה תחלה

Comment: Bloodletting isn't so common nowadays indeed. Though see this http://parsha.blogspot.com/2007/08/why-i-oppose-refuah-card.html

Comment: How about saying assusah after someone sneezes?

Comment: Possible superstitious practice, so unless it is your minhag I would say don't resurrect the practice. More here http://parsha.blogspot.com/2010/12/salvation-nothing-to-sneeze-at.html?m=1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Saadia Gaon didn't innovate it. It is based on [Berachot 60a](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A1_%D7%90):

> ת"ר הנכנס לבית המרחץ אומר יהי רצון מלפניך יי' אלהי שתצילני מזה ומכיוצא בו ואל יארע בי דבר קלקלה ועון ואם יארע בי דבר קלקלה ועון תהא מיתתי כפרה לכל עונותי אמר אביי לא לימא אינש הכי דלא לפתח פומיה לשטן
>
> Our Rabbis taught: On entering a bath-house one should say: 'May it be Thy will O Lord, my God, to deliver me from this and from the like of this, and let no humiliation or iniquity befall me; and if I do fall into any perversity or iniquity, may my death be an atonement for all my iniquities'. Abaye said: A man should not speak thus, so as not to open his mouth for the Satan.19

Except Saadia Gaon's formulation is more explicit about the danger: "Blessed are You, O God, Who has saved me from the fire."

Given this, there are two obvious answers:

1) Are you in danger from fire when you take a bath? Their bath houses are not the same as our bathrooms, such that the **formulation** of the blessing, and indeed, the very **reason** for the blessing (the danger), is uprooted.

2) Even in the gemara, Abaye argues. While Saadia Gaon evidently held one way, perhaps other Rabbinic figures held otherwise.